# C vs C++ sizeof

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

I just came across this simple code snippet and am wondering why output of this program when it's compiled by a C compiler is `4` and when it's compiled by a C++ one is `8`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x;

int main(){
    struct x {int a; int b;};
    printf("%d", sizeof(x));
    return 0;
}
```

C++ output is rational (`8 = 4 + 4 = sizeof(x.a) + sizeof(x.b)`), but output of C isn't. So, how does `sizeof` work in C?

- C : https://ideone.com/zj5Qd2
- C++ : https://ideone.com/ZZ4v6S

Seems C prefers global variables over local ones. Is it right?

Comment: As much as I can remember in C you cannot ommit `struct` unless you typedef it

Comment: This is a known trick for the interview question 'how would you write a program which would print out C or C++ depending on it's compiler without use of any preprocessor macro'

Comment: @SergeyA Much more simply, check `sizeof('a')`.

Comment: @black: That doesn't distinguish between C++ and a C implementation with `sizeof (int) == 1` (which implies `CHAR_BIT >= 16`).

Comment: @KeithThompson: Before `sizeof('a')`, `if (sizeof(int) == 1) goto hell;`.

Comment: The correct format for printing a `size_t` value (such as the result of `sizeof`) is `"%zu"`, not `"%d"`. Or, if you're stuck with an old implementation that doesn't support it: `printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(x));`. (The `\n` is highly recommended; failing print a newline at the end of a text stream may cause undefined behavior.)

Comment: "...prefers global variables over local ones"? In C++ version `x` is not a "variable". It is a type.

Comment: @SergeyA Let's just hope that anyone doing interview questions now won't pick that thinking it's a *good* question.

Comment: @user694733, dependng on conditions, it might be a good question. For example, if the job requires doing a lot of development in both languages, people should be familiar with differences between them.

Comment: @SergeyA But does it tell you that? He might understand differences in C and C++, but has never heard of this trick. Most people would use __cplusplus macro, and disallowing that is rather arbitrary. Better question would be *"Why must you avoid compiling C programs with C++ compiler?"*

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In C, a struct definition like `struct x { int a; int b; };` does not define a type `x`, it defines a type `struct x`.  So if you remove the `int x;` global, you'll find the C version does not compile.

Comment: My brain entirely glossed over the the global declaration of `x`.